# Tkinter Button to refresh data via API call

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm complete noob in Tkinter library and function calling so I'm turning to you for some help:

I try to create a widget to check cryptocurrency prices and PNL.

So far, I've created CoinGecko API call inside a function to return me a dataframe and PNL result.
I've also created GUI with Tkinter.

My current script looks like this:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from tkinter import *
import time

def get_crypto_data():
    data = []
    cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
    coins = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin,ethereum,,neo,ripple', vs_currencies='usd', include_24hr_change='true')
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(coins, orient='index')

    PNL = "something"
    data.append(df)
    data.append(PNL)

    return data

def Click():
    get_crypto_data()

def setup_GUI(mask,crypto_data, click):

    mask.wm_title("Live Portfolio Data")

    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

    l1 = Label(mask,bg='blue', text= "Live Crypto portfolio Data")
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    l2 = Label(mask,bg='yellow', text= date_time)
    l2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    l3 = Label(mask,bg='yellow', text=crypto_data[0])
    l3.grid(row=2, column=0)
    l4 = Label(mask, bg='yellow', text=crypto_data[1])
    l4.grid(row=3, column=0)
    butt = Button(mask, padx=2, bd=2, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
                   text="Button", bg="yellow", command=lambda: Click())
    butt.grid(row=5, column=0)
    mask.geometry("500x500")
    mask.configure(bg='yellow')
    return mask

def main():

    while True:

        mask = Tk()
        crypto_data = get_crypto_data()
        click = Click()
        mask = setup_GUI(mask,crypto_data,click)
        mask.update()
        mask.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I'm trying to do is to make Button API call and refresh dataframe and PNL and show it on my mask.

Do you have any ideas how to make this happen? I guess it's not that difficult, but I don't know where to look :)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `tkinter.Tk`. I edited your code accordingly:

```py
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from tkinter import *
import time

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self) # initiate the window
    
    def setup_ui(self):
        self.wm_title("Live Portfolio Data")

        date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

        self.l1 = Label(self, bg="blue", text="Live Crypto portfolio Data")
        self.l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.l2 = Label(self, bg="yellow", text=date_time)
        self.l2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.l3 = Label(self, bg="yellow", text="placeholder") # placeholder will be replaced with correct values
        self.l3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.l4 = Label(self, bg="yellow", text="placeholder")
        self.l4.grid(row=3, column=0)
        butt = Button(self, padx=2, bd=2, fg="black", font=("arial", 20, "bold"),
                   text="Button", bg="yellow", command=self.update_data) # when the user clicks the button, fetch the data again and update the labels
        butt.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.configure(bg="yellow")
        self.update_data() # call update_data once to display correct values on the labels

    def update_data(self, *args): # *args makes accept this function any number of arguments, args will be a list with all arguments
        self.data = [] # make data a member of this class
        cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
        coins = cg.get_price(ids="bitcoin,ethereum,neo,ripple", vs_currencies="usd", include_24hr_change="true")
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(coins, orient="index")

        PNL = "something"
        self.data.append(df)
        self.data.append(PNL)
        
        date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") # if you do not want
        self.l2.config(text=date_time) # the time to be updated, remove these two lines
        
        # update labels with values got above
        self.l3.config(text=self.data[0])
        self.l4.config(text=self.data[1])

def main():
    mask = Window() # create window
    mask.setup_ui() # create labels, buttons, etc.
    mask.update() # make sure everything shows up correctly
    mask.mainloop() # now show the window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please use either single quotes (`'`) OR double quotes (`"`) everywhere in your code. It is no problem for python to use both mixed, but it makes code more readable to NOT mix them.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt help, but honesly, I don't quite understand how it works. Even if I run your script it shows error: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'l3' Can you please expain a little?

Comment: @MachuPichu92 yes later this evening !

Comment: @MachuPichu92 i edited my answer, its running without errors now, and i added comments to explain what the code is doing

Comment: @MachuPichu92 i must admit i did not test my first code ;) sorry for that

Comment: frederic: Thanks a lot for adiitonal explanation and your time!

Comment: @MachuPichu92 no problem !

Comment: @MachuPichu92 PLEASE accept my answer by clicking the gray checkmark on the left of my answer, it will then turn green